# Time Machine restore stuck on “Preparing <destination disk>” for more than 24 hours, how can I diagnose the nature of the problem?

Tags: time-machine, restore, high-sierra, filevault, raid

Recently [I got myself into quite a pickle that eventually required I format my Mac’s dual-SSD RAID-0 array and restore from a Time Machine backup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306633/apfs-on-raid-recommended-course-of-action).

Unfortunately Time Machine has spent the past 24 hours stuck on “Preparing [destination disk]” and shows absolutely no sign of progress. (The backup is hosted on a Time Capsule-emulating Synology NAS.) There is no information on what is going on behind the scenes, just a solid pulsing blue progress bar that doesn’t even initialize and start creeping rightwards. Before the process began there was some cryptic remark about encryption needing to be disabled subsequently re-enabled as FileVault once restoring is complete, and I authorized the request to erase the destination disk.

Quite suspiciously it asks me to acknowledge disabling encryption every time I restart the process, which might imply that some latent form of FileVault is lingering, but I have erased the disk several times and each time explicitly instructed the system to format as JHFS+, unencrypted and case-insensitive.

(Keep in mind that “disk” in this context actually means RAID volume, as the two physical SSDs each host slices of the unified striped RAID-0 volume.)

I tried dropping into the Terminal because I vaguely remember the

```
tmutil
```

commmand but it is not present in the barebones toolkit of the macOS installer.

Can somebody help me figure out what is going on?

Thanks.

(Tragic aside: while in a panic and desperately trying to unmake my unbootable APFS-formatted RAID array which I created and that got me into this pickle, I accidentally nuked my FireWire-attached CarbonCopyCloner backup, so I’m stuck using Apple’s blunt instrument with no information whatsoever.)

Comment: FYI, this is NOT the same issue as stuck on "Preparing Backup" - "Preparing <destination disk>" is part of the initial process of setting up the disk to be a TimeMachine volume. The issues here are different from the typical problems in scanning for changes that causes a working backup set to hang at "Preparing Backup".

Answer (score 1):

I have since discovered that [Apple has fully deprecated support for the APFS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208018) and that consequentially restoring from a network-attached device (as is my Synology NAS) requires re-sharing with the SMB protocol.

Comment: Did this work for you? I’m having the same unresolving “Preparing “volume name”...” issue restoring to a dual SSD RAID0 array from an encrypted time machine backup. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!